# How to create JSON files with Python correclty?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON file with financial data from Yahoo.
I can parse all the data from the website. But unfortunately I can't find a way to create the JSON file correctly. It seems like the JSON objects are not concatenated in the right way.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Please find the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json
import ast
import os
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import datetime

# For ignoring SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Input from the user (temp. manually)
urls = [
    'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DB1.DE?p=DB1.DE'
    , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ALV.DE?p=ALV.DE&.tsrc=fin-srch'
    , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FME.DE?p=FME.DE'
    , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DBK.DE?p=DBK.DE'
]

# Making the website believe that you are accessing it using a Mozilla browser
for url in urls:
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()

# Creating a BeautifulSoup object of the HTML page for easy extraction of data.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
    html = soup.prettify('utf-8')
    world_ana_json = {}

    for h1 in soup.findAll('h1'):
        world_ana_json['TICKER'] = h1.text.strip()
    for span in soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'}):
        world_ana_json['PRESENT_VALUE'] = span.text.strip()
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'}):
        for span in div.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['PRESENT_GROWTH'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PREV_CLOSE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['PREV_CLOSE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'OPEN-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['OPEN'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BID-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['BID'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'ASK-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['ASK'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'DAYS_RANGE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['DAYS_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'TD_VOLUME-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['TD_VOLUME'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'MARKET_CAP-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['MARKET_CAP'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BETA_3Y-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['BETA_3Y'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PE_RATIO-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['PE_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EPS_RATIO-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['EPS_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EARNINGS_DATE-value'}):
        world_ana_json['EARNINGS_DATE'] = []
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['EARNINGS_DATE'].append(span.text.strip())
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD-value'}):
        world_ana_json['DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD'] = td.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'EX_DIVIDEND_DATE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['EX_DIVIDEND_DATE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value' }):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE'] = span.text.strip()
    world_ana_json['PARSE_DATE'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    with open('world_ana_kpis.json', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(world_ana_json, outfile, indent=4)
    print world_ana_json
    print '----------Iteration complete.----------'

print '----------Extraction of data is complete. Check json file.----------'
```

This is the JSON result:

```
{
    "TD_VOLUME": "684,446", 
    "MARKET_CAP": "24.882B", 
    "OPEN": "134.05", 
    "BID": "135.15 x 3500", 
    "AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH": "849,271", 
    "PREV_CLOSE": "132.65", 
    "EARNINGS_DATE": [
        "Feb 13, 2018", 
        "Feb 19, 2018"
    ], 
    "DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD": "2.90 (2.19%)", 
    "EPS_RATIO": "5.47", 
    "PARSE_DATE": "2020-04-14 22:06:45.339815", 
    "PE_RATIO": "24.80", 
    "ASK": "135.10 x 14200", 
    "PRESENT_VALUE": "135.65", 
    "TICKER": "DB1.DE - Deutsche Borse AG", 
    "EX_DIVIDEND_DATE": "May 20, 2020", 
    "ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE": "119.75"
}{
    "TD_VOLUME": "1,841,919", 
    "MARKET_CAP": "69.86B", 
    "OPEN": "168.72", 
    "BID": "167.66 x 214900", 
    "AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH": "2,259,476", 
    "PREV_CLOSE": "164.88", 
    "EARNINGS_DATE": [
        "May 12, 2020"
    ], 
    "DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD": "9.60 (5.82%)", 
    "EPS_RATIO": "18.83", 
    "PARSE_DATE": "2020-04-14 22:06:46.592483", 
    "PE_RATIO": "8.91", 
    "ASK": "167.74 x 10000", 
    "PRESENT_VALUE": "167.70", 
    "TICKER": "ALV.DE - Allianz SE", 
    "EX_DIVIDEND_DATE": "May 07, 2020", 
    "ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE": "213.69"
}{
    "TD_VOLUME": "912,856", 
    "MARKET_CAP": "19.246B", 
    "OPEN": "64.26", 
    "BID": "63.98 x 38700", 
    "AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH": "1,293,817", 
    "PREV_CLOSE": "63.24", 
    "EARNINGS_DATE": [
        "May 06, 2020"
    ], 
    "DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD": "1.20 (1.90%)", 
    "EPS_RATIO": "3.96", 
    "PARSE_DATE": "2020-04-14 22:06:48.157705", 
    "PE_RATIO": "16.18", 
    "ASK": "64.04 x 105300", 
    "PRESENT_VALUE": "64.06", 
    "TICKER": "FME.DE - Fresenius Medical Care AG & Co. KGaA", 
    "EX_DIVIDEND_DATE": "May 20, 2020", 
    "ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE": "80.61"
}{
    "TD_VOLUME": "15,877,455", 
    "MARKET_CAP": "12.828B", 
    "OPEN": "6.20", 
    "BID": "6.19 x 555100", 
    "AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH": "25,845,616", 
    "PREV_CLOSE": "6.12", 
    "EARNINGS_DATE": [
        "Apr 29, 2020"
    ], 
    "DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD": "0.11 (1.82%)", 
    "EPS_RATIO": "-2.71", 
    "PARSE_DATE": "2020-04-14 22:06:49.821249", 
    "PE_RATIO": "N/A", 
    "ASK": "6.19 x 230000", 
    "PRESENT_VALUE": "6.21", 
    "TICKER": "DBK.DE - Deutsche Bank Aktiengesellschaft", 
    "EX_DIVIDEND_DATE": "May 24, 2019", 
    "ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE": "N/A"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing to file in a for loop, there is no "," between json object and all the json objects should be in an array.

I have modified the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json
import ast
import os
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import datetime

# For ignoring SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Input from the user (temp. manually)
urls = [
    'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DB1.DE?p=DB1.DE'
    , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ALV.DE?p=ALV.DE&.tsrc=fin-srch'
    , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FME.DE?p=FME.DE'
    , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DBK.DE?p=DBK.DE'
]

output = []

# Making the website believe that you are accessing it using a Mozilla browser
for url in urls:
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()

# Creating a BeautifulSoup object of the HTML page for easy extraction of data.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
    html = soup.prettify('utf-8')
    world_ana_json = {}

    for h1 in soup.findAll('h1'):
        world_ana_json['TICKER'] = h1.text.strip()
    for span in soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'}):
        world_ana_json['PRESENT_VALUE'] = span.text.strip()
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'}):
        for span in div.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['PRESENT_GROWTH'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PREV_CLOSE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['PREV_CLOSE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'OPEN-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['OPEN'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BID-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['BID'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'ASK-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['ASK'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'DAYS_RANGE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['DAYS_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'TD_VOLUME-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['TD_VOLUME'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'MARKET_CAP-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['MARKET_CAP'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BETA_3Y-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['BETA_3Y'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PE_RATIO-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['PE_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EPS_RATIO-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['EPS_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EARNINGS_DATE-value'}):
        world_ana_json['EARNINGS_DATE'] = []
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['EARNINGS_DATE'].append(span.text.strip())
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD-value'}):
        world_ana_json['DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD'] = td.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'EX_DIVIDEND_DATE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['EX_DIVIDEND_DATE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value' }):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            world_ana_json['ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE'] = span.text.strip()
    world_ana_json['PARSE_DATE'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    output.append(world_ana_json);

with open('world_ana_kpis.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(output, outfile, indent=4)

print '----------Extraction of data is complete. Check json file.----------'
```